# how to maintain aspect ratio in flash as3 video

Tags: flash

I have created a flash video player using as3 (videoObject) but when I play the video the video is streched how to tell flash using as3 to maintain aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use:

```
myVideo.scaleMode = "maintainAspectRatio";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're putting it up online, you could always use HTML to do so:

Flash will do this for you, automatically, if you publish your file (`File -> publish`).